# var_dump() output in a variable

Tags: php, var-dump

Is is possible I can assign output of `var_dump($var)` to a variable? As a default behavior, var_dump() just prints output on screen. I want to append or assign its output to other variable and then output that later on. Like:

```
$a = true;
$b = var_dump($a);
echo $b;
```

Comment: Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: As described in manual `var_dump` returns no value. But you can use `ob_*` functions

Comment: I want check when $a becomes false in a loop, in which an HTML output is being appended to $html. I want to append $a's var_dump for dubuggin

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please post the loop code as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or you could just use

```
$content=var_export($variable,true)
echo $content;
```

Reference: http://www.php.net/var_export

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to do it in the following way, using the [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

```
<?php
ob_start();
var_dump($a);
$result = ob_get_clean();

echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

var_export with return value set to true.

You can also use function calls

```
$result[] = var_export($class->function($otherClass->otherFunction['id']), true);
```